# Getting specific data from a firebase collection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter app where I'm trying to get a specific data from Firebase a save it into a variable. In Firebase, I'm using Firestore Database and the structure of my database is like that:

[image]

I'm trying to get the data using this method:

```
  void getItems() async {
    var test;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("userData")
        .doc(Constant.loginID)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) => print(doc.data()) );
  
  }
```

With this  code I get the data of a specific document and that is okay, however I get all the data of that document and I only want "useItems" data, How I can do it?

Comment: The Firestore client-side SDKs always loads complete documents, and cannot load a subset of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge ,from cloud firestore collection you can query from subcollection, but not form tis Map

so if you get need only userItem then (you will get all data to the app and take needed data form app side)

```
 void getItems() async {
var test;
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("userData")
    .doc(Constant.loginID)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) => print(doc.data['userItem']) );
```

or Create a model Class and use userItem object;

you can also do it from ui side

```
class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
  _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
   }

     class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = 
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();

    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
     stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, 
     AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading");
    }

    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(data['userItem']),
       
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
);
  }
 }
```

Comment: your code not work because "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'" however, actually I get all data, so how I can take needed data?

Comment: updated can you try both methods? for more  visit  
  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Comment: The first one does not, however the second one does not give me any error. However, this is not my objective, I mean I don't want to show the data I want to get the data and save it in a variable as string